# ¿Capitalizar cada palabra de una oracion? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Estimados, requiero de la ayuda de sus mentes sabias.

De una tabla nombre "Detalles" contiene la columna "Descrip", la cual puede contener datos alfanuméricos y puede tener X cantidad de palabras, ejemplo.

```
[Descrip]
01. reMunerAcion feBrero 2017
02. enERO eMP 141414
03. 20178233 NOVIEMBRE
```

El resultado esperado:

```
[Descrip]
01. Remuneracion Febrero 2017
02. Enero Emp 141414
03. 20178233 Noviembre
```

He intentado realizarlo de la siguiente forma pero solo logro capitalizar la primera palabra de la oración con la siguiente sentencia:

```
UPDATE DETALLES
SET 
Descrip=UPPER(LEFT(Descrip,1))
+LOWER(SUBSTRING(Descrip,2,LEN(Descrip)))
```

¿Alguna idea de como lograrlo? Lo he buscado pero no encuentro que realice para cada frase. SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es una función que te ayude a recorrer cada palabra en cada registro de la columna "Descrip". En este apartado de StackOverflow (ingles) lo puedes encontrar:

[SQL: capitalize first letter only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290754/sql-capitalize-first-letter-only)

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Edito: Funciona perfecto!!!!!